# What does this categorical construction do?

Tags: category-theory

I've come across the following categorical construction:

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a category. Let $\mathbf{C}^{\prime}$ be the category whose objects are tuples $(X_i)_{i\in I}$, where $I$ is some set and $X_i,i\in I$ is an object in $\mathbf{C}$. The morphisms between two objects $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(Y_j)_{j\in J}$ are given by a map $f\colon I\rightarrow J$ and a morphism $f_i\colon X_i\rightarrow Y_{f(i)}$ for each $i\in I$. The composition of a morphism $(X_i)_{i\in I}\stackrel{(f,(f_i)_{i\in I})}{\longrightarrow}(Y_j)_{j\in J}$ and a morphism $(Y_j)_{j\in J}\stackrel{(g,(g_j)_{j\in J})}{\longrightarrow}(Z_k)_{k\in K}$ is given by $(X_i)_{i\in I}\stackrel{(g\circ f,(g_{f(i)}\circ f_i)_{i\in I})}{\longrightarrow}(Z_k)_{k\in K}$. The identity morphism on $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ is $(\mathrm{id}_I,(\mathrm{id}_{X_i})_{i\in I})$ and the relevant axioms are immediate from the respective axioms in $\mathbf{Set}$ and $\mathbf{C}$.

My question is: What is this construction/What does it do? Does this admit a nice description in terms of known categorical constructions? It may be worth pointing out that an object $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ in $\mathbf{C}^{\prime}$ can be thought of as a functor from $\mathbf{I}$, the discrete category with $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathbf{I})=I$, to $\mathbf{C}$ and that the morphisms in $\mathbf{C}^{\prime}$ are just collections of morphisms in $\mathbf{C}$, which are "intertwined" by some functor $\mathbf{I}\rightarrow\mathbf{J}$, but I don't know how to make this precise.

Comment: I find it difficult to explain adequately why this is a very interesting thing, so I can't leave an answer; but if $\mathbf{C}$ is small, what you describe is the total category of the *externalization* or *family fibration* of $\mathbf{C}$. It's neat because it generalizes to internal categories in settings other than $\mathbf{Set}$ and is a really helpful tool for talking about the structure of internal categories in those settings.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'll try looking into that.

Comment: No problem! If your library has a copy, I really recommend Borceux's *Handbook of Categorical Algebra* vol. 2, or Jacobs's *Categorical Logic and Type Theory* for the subject.

Comment: This looks to me like freely adjoining coproducts to $\mathbf C$. The idea is that the family $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ serves as the coproduct of the objects $X_i$. The morphisms from such a coproduct to another one $(Y_j)_{j\in J}$ should amount (by definition of coproducts) to $I$-indexed families of maps, one from each $X_i$ into $(Y_j)_{j\in J}$. Your definition of morphisms amounts to this plus the extra information that each $X_i$ maps into a single $Y_j$. I expect that to be a manifestation of *freely* adjoining coproducts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of perhaps many perspectives is the following:

This is essentially a 2-categorical analog of a [slice/comma category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/comma+category).

In this case, it is the full 1-subcategory of the [colax slice 2-category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/slice+2-category) $\newcommand\Set{\mathbf{Set}}\newcommand\Cat{\mathbf{Cat}}\newcommand\C{\mathcal{C}}\Cat/\C$ on the objects which are sets regarded as small discrete categories.

I'll rewrite the definition of the colax slice 2-category here (particularly as it's not explicitly spelled out on the nlab page):

Let $\newcommand\B{\mathcal{B}}\B$ be a 2-category. Let $X$ be an object of $\B$. The colax slice 2-category $\B/X$ is defined to have

**0-cells:** $\B$-morphisms $a:A\to X$.

**1-cells:** If $a:A\to X$ and $b:B\to X$ are 0-cells, then a 1-cell $(f,\phi):a\to b$ is 
a pair of a $\B$-morphism $f:A\to B$ and a $\B$-2-cell $\phi : a\to bf$.

The composition of $(f,\phi):a\to b$ and $(g,\psi):b\to c$ is the pair
$$(gf : A\to C, (\psi\operatorname{.} f)\phi : a\to bf \to cgf).$$

**2-cells:** If $(f,\phi),(g,\psi): a\to b$, a 2-cell $\alpha : (f,\phi)\to (g,\psi)$ is a 2-cell of $\B$, $\alpha : f\to g$, such that $\psi = (b\operatorname{.}\alpha)\phi$ as $\B$-2-cells from $a \to bg$

**In our case**

Specializing to our case, $\B=\Cat$, $X=\C$, and we restrict the domains of the $0$-cells to be sets, and then if we forget about 2-cells, we get exactly the construction from the question. Namely, objects are functors $i:I\to \C$, and morphisms $i\to j$ are pairs of a function $f:I\to J$ and a natural transformation $\phi: i\to jf$.

The composition also agrees with the composition in the question.

**End note on philosophy and intuition of this perspective**

Reading the question, what jumps out at me is that it looks a lot like a slice category or arrow category, since the objects are arrows. The next thought is that it's definitely a slice category, since the codomains are all the same. However the morphisms are different than in the 1-categorical slice category, since the triangles are only required to commute up to a homotopy. My next thought is that this looks exactly like what I'd expect a 2-categorical slice category to be, but we'd best be careful about what directions the homotopies go, since we aren't forcing them to be isomorphisms so I Google lax slice category, and up pops the nlab page linked above.